# Collapse dashed borders on non-table

Tags: css

```css
#grid {
    display: grid;
    grid: auto / repeat(3, 1fr);
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}

#grid div {
    border: 1px dashed black;
    border-radius: 12px;
    height: 100%;
}

#grid div:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#grid div:nth-child(3) {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

The problem with my snippet is that meeting borders overlap. If I try to fix that by applying negative margin `-1px`, it looks okay, but the now "merged" borders display as solid on some screens.

I'd like to:

1. merge meeting borders
2. avoid merged borders from appearing solid

All without targeting specific children of the grid.

Comment: I don't think what you want is really possible. Whether or not the borders become "solid", when you overlap them, depends on how long a browser renders those dashes to begin with, combined with how much your vertical offset between those divs is.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is disable the right border for all childs except the last one so each one would have only one border which will not merge.

```css
#grid {
    display: grid;
    grid: auto / repeat(3, 1fr);
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
}

#grid div {
    border: 1px dashed black;
    border-radius: 12px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -1px;
}

#grid div:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#grid div:nth-child(3) {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Check if this works as you expect.

after applying `margin-right: -1px` it works and the borders dont even look solid

Comment: Sorry, see edited snippet. It makes it even more difficult than that

Comment: Hey @Ravenous, Did you check the edited answer? is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, but your solution doesn't fix the issue of overlapping dashed borders. The comment by CBroe is right, it's just not possible, I'm not overlooking anything.